# How to show data from database in a listview?

Tags: android

I have written some thing like this to fetch data from the database.

```
public String getData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_SCORE};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(
                DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";

    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
    int iHotness = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SCORE);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iName) + " " + c.getString(iHotness) + "\n";
    }

    return result;
}
```

and i am able to show data into textview. But i want to show data into listview can anyone suggest me or give me a sample code to show data into listview. I had taken a list.xml and put a listview in that. I want to fetch data from the database.

thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html try with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public String[] getData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_SCORE};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    //Initialise the result variable
    String[] result = new String[c.getCount()];

    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
    int iHotness = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SCORE);
    int counter = 0;
    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        result[counter] = c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iName) + " " + c.getString(iHotness) + "\n";
        counter++;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Then in the ListView onCreate you add the result string to you adapter.

```
   setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, result));
```

Comment: You forgot to return String[] instead of String

Comment: it is giving error as "Variable must provide either dimension expressions or an array initializer "...  the error is at String[] result =new String[];

Comment: It should work now (my edit needs peer reviewing before it can be seen)

Answer (score 1):

Showing data in a list isn't as simple as saying `getListView().setData(myData);`

First, create a list adapter, this is a class that takes some data (usually as an ArrayList) and 'gives' it to the list in a way the list can read.

Take a look at the developer docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html

And some tutorials:

- http://jnastase.alner.net/archive/2010/12/19/custom-android-listadapter.aspx
- http://united-coders.com/phillip-steffensen/android-dealing-with-listactivities-customized-listadapters-and-custom-designed-0
- http://trace.adityalesmana.com/2010/08/customize-android-listview-via-listadapter/

Comment: so how to set the data .the links are bit confusing .can u give any code to demonstrate it ..